# no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::ifstream,char)

Tags: c++, getline

beginner c++ user here
I have trying to take in lines from a file in put it into a string array. The file has each word on its own line. Whenever I tested the array it appeared it was loading each letter into the array. So it was chars instead each word as a string. The first thing in each file is a number that will be the array size. I was supposed to dynamically allocate the array's which I believe I did correctly. 
Any help is welcome. 
I am using VScode, and the issue that getline gives me is, no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::ifstream,char).

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int showMenuGetChoice();
   string createStringArray(int);
   void getInfoFromUser(string, string, int);
   void printStory(int, string, int);

   // Calls all the other functions to make a working Madlibs game. 
 int main ()
 {
    int UserChoice;

    ifstream QuestionFile;
    int arraySize;
    string Question;
    int test = 0;
    do {

    cout <<"Let's Play some Madlibs!!" << endl << endl;
    UserChoice=showMenuGetChoice();

    if (UserChoice == 1)
    {
        ifstream QuestionFile;
        QuestionFile.open("starWars.txt");
        QuestionFile >> arraySize;
        cin.ignore();

        string QuestionArray=createStringArray(arraySize);

        if(QuestionFile.is_open())
        {
            QuestionArray[arraySize];

            for(int i=0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                getline(QuestionFile, QuestionArray[i]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            cout << QuestionArray[i] << endl;
        }

      }

// Takes in a integer and creates a array of that size. Dynamically allocates the array and returns a point to this array.
string createStringArray(int n)
{
    string*QuestionArray = new string[n];

    return *QuestionArray;
}
```

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to fix on my question, or is the edited version now correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error:

> no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
>   -- argument types are: (std::ifstream,char).

Because of a problem with your "getline" call:

```
getline(QuestionFile, QuestionArray[i]);
```

`std::getline` accepts two parameters, a `std::istream` reference and a **`std::string`** reference. `QuestionFile` is an `istream`, so that's okay, however if you review the declaration of `QuestionArray`:

```
string QuestionArray=createStringArray(arraySize);
```

You should notice that QuestionArray is a variable of `string` type. I don't think this is what you intended. You should always carefully choose the type of variables you declare in C++, otherwise you are working against the type safety the compiler is trying to provide you with.

The `i`th element of the string `QuestionArray` is a `char`, not a `string`. This is the cause of the compiler error. You are trying to place the line into a single character element instead of a string.

Hopefully with the above explanation, the compiler message provided will make more sense now. It's providing the same information, just a little more condensed.

With that knowledge, lets address the `createStringArray` function:

```
string createStringArray(int n)
{
    string*QuestionArray = new string[n];

    return *QuestionArray;
}
```

You declare the function to return a single string, when I expect you want the function to return an sequence of strings. The correct way to return an sequence of strings is to use `std::vector<std::string>`, but if you must use risky, outdated, manual memory management you'll need to return a **pointer** to string, not a string from this function. With that knowledge you should be able to correct this function, the original `QuestionArray` variable type, and the compiler error should go away.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am supposed to use arrays for this program so I cannot use vectors. If I am understanding correctly its trying to put chars in the indexs of the QuestionArray instead of putting the whole word. I do not fully understand the fix that I need to do, if I am not using vectors.

Comment: @Grima_Sovnig: You'll need to start by correcting the declaration of `QuestionArray` in `main()`. It needs to be a pointer to an array of strings, not a string. The return type of `createStringArray` needs to be corrected for the same reason. In `createStringArray`, you need to review your syntax very carefully. `return *QuestionArray` does not return a pointer. The `*` means something different in declarations and expressions.

Comment: More hints: `string *QuestionArray = new string[n]` is probably correct, it's declaring a "pointer to an array of strings".... `string QuestionArray=createStringArray(arraySize);` is wrong, you are declaring a `string`, but that's not what you want....... `return *QuestionArray` is wrong, you want to return a "pointer to an array of strings". QuestionArray is a "pointer to an array of strings", but what does the `*` do?